# Python says that elif statement is a Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and I have just started to learn from a book that I have recently bought. 
I am at the if, elif and else chapter.
I have copied the code from the book, and I ran it.
Suddenly, it says about "elif", that is a Syntax Error.
Please help

```py
num = int(input('Please Enter A Number:'))
if num > 5:
    print('Number Exceeds 5')
    elif num < 5:
        print('Number is Less than 5')
        else:
            print('Number is 5')
```

Comment: Indentation. You have to indent properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, indentation is key. You need to make sure your indentation is proper. Please change your code as follows, it should work.

In your code `elif` is not a part of your `if` block, therefore, it should be outside it.

```
num = int(input('Please Enter A Number:'))
if num > 5:
    print('Number Exceeds 5')
elif num < 5:
    print('Number is Less than 5')
else:
    print('Number is 5')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python indenting matters because it is used to control code execution flow.

Your `if`, `elif`, and `else` statements in your code should all be at the same level of indent:

```
num = int(input('Please Enter A Number:'))
if num > 5:
    print('Number Exceeds 5')
elif num < 5:
    print('Number is Less than 5')
else:
    print('Number is 5')
```